# Problem with \section[][]{} when using memoir

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir

I am writing a book using the memoir document class. When I use `\chapter[ToC title][Header title]{Division title}`, at the chapter level everything works correctly. At the section level however things are a little strange. When I use `\section[ToC title][Header title]{Division title}` the division title in the main body of the text appears, for example, as:

> 2.1 [

with "ToC title" appearing in the table of contents and in the header.

Just for the fun of it I tried \section[ToC title]Header{Division title} and get:

> 2.1 H

with "ToC title" appearing in both the table of contents and header.

Using `\section[ToC title]{Division title}` everything works as it should but I want the table of contents and division titles to be identical but different from the header title.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: On preparing a MWE with the problem described above its root cause seems to stem from using the package \usepackage{titlesec} in the preamble. Commenting it out and everything seems to work.

Comment: Have you read the link I provided? You say that you have some output (`2.1. [`). Therefore there exists a document which produces it. Take this one and make it a minimal example. Btw, AFAIK `titlesec` is incompatible with `memoir`, but that's exactly why MWE is needed.